# how to keep the value in python's lambda closure

Tags: python, closures

I'm trying to iterate a list and trigger threads to process long waiting network calls in parallel for each item of the list. But python's closure doesn't work as I imagined and does not preserve the value of the list item at that specific loop. So all threads receive the last list item as parameter and have the same counter value.

How should I pass each list item as parameter to each thread?

```
print("Downloading stock data...")
stocks = Stock.objects.all()
counter = 1
tasks = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for stock in stocks:
        my_lambda = lambda: parallel_test(stock, counter)
        tasks.append(executor.submit(my_lambda))
        counter += 1

    for running_task in tasks:
        running_task.result()


def parallel_test(stock: Stock, counter: int):
    try:
        (... a network call with long waiting time)
    finally:
        print(f"Stock {counter} {stock.name} downloaded!")
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions that may help!

Comment: You can use `counter=Counter(1)` from `collections` instead. Use `next(counter)` for the next value.